# Possible bug in Microsoft Release Manager when using multiple "Manual Intervention" actions

Tags: action, ms-release-management, intervention

When a template defines multiple **Manual Intervention** actions, the "Date Started" is incorrect. For the second Manual Intervention, the Date Started is the same although this second step is actually approved several minutes after the first step.
Is this a known issue?

**Deployment Sequence:**
[image]

**Deployment Log:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `Date Started` is when the manual intervention was created - meaning when the workflow got to that activity during execution. The `Duration` column will tell you when it was actually approved - or really how much time it took someone to approve it

Comment: The problem is that there are two Manual Interventions, but both get the same "Date Started" which is strange because they are not started at the same time because the actions in between take also some time (see the screenshot).

Comment: I see. I thought this was a parallel execution... Can you share your deployment sequence?

Comment: Added screenshot for the sequence.